# Showing $(a^{k_n})\to a^k$ whenever $(k_n)\to k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If the sequence $(k_n)\to k$, is it possible to show $(a^{k_n})\to a^k$ without having to involve the theory of limits of functions.

i.e., to show that $\forall\varepsilon > 0, \exists K\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n\ge K$ we have $\mid a^{k_n}-a^k\mid < \varepsilon.$

Rudin uses this result in one of the [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799180/examples-3-35-a-and-b-in-baby-rudin-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior-of-a) in a chapter which comes before  concept of limits of functions.

Comment: Write down the definition of continuity for the real function $a^x$ and the definition of convergence to $k$ for the sequence $(k_n)$: with these two facts you should see immediately how to prove what you asked.

Comment: How you do this will depend on the definition of $a^k$, in particular for irrational $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that
$$
\left|a^{k_n}-a^k\right|=\left|a^k\left(a^{\left(k_n-k\right)}-1\right)\right|=\left|a^k\right|\left|a^{\left(k_n-k\right)}-1\right|,
$$
you may then apply your $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument with respect to $\left|k_n-k\right|$, as per your value of $a$ of course.

Comment: Case (i) $a=0,$ the answer is trivial. Case (ii) $a\ne 0$ 

Since $(k_n)\to k, \exists K\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n\ge K $ we have $\mid k_n - k\mid < \log_a (\frac{\varepsilon}{|a^k|}+1)$. 

Thus for any given $\varepsilon$ we have $\mid a^{k_n} - a^k\mid < \varepsilon, \forall n\ge K.$

Comment: @BijeshK.S: Awesome!